# Why isn't S concave in Maxwell's thermodynamic surface?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

Maxwell's thermodynamic surface represents S(U,V) for a substance like water.

We showed in class that S is concave, so why isn't it the case here?

From Wikipedia:

[image: Maxwell's thermodynamic surface]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's an intriguing question. I had to read the original pages by Maxwell ( Maxwell, James Clerk (1995-01-01). Maxwell on Heat and Statistical Mechanics: On "Avoiding All Personal Enquiries" of Molecules. p. 248. ISBN 9780934223348.) to check if my guess was correct.

Indeed, the surface does not represent the set of equilibrium points, which should have the correct convexity everywhere. Like van der Waals' isotherms, this surface contains also regions of wrong convexity where the system would be unstable against a phase separation.

It turns out that J.C. Maxwell made three 3D models like this, using the shadow created by grazing sunlight in order the local tangent planes and lines of equal pressure and temperature. By the way, as far as I understand, the model should represent energy (on the vertical axis) as a function of entropy and volume.